# What does "Native library location" entry do in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, native

If adding user-defined library in Eclipse, one has an ability to set "Native library location". This field allows to enter some directory path.

When does this path plays a part?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eclipse uses this information to build the `java.library.path` when it launches a Java program.

Background: Some Java frameworks depend on native code. This code usually comes in the form of a native shared library (*.so, *.dll). In Java, you can see methods with the attribute `native`. The code will load the shared library using `System.loadLibrary()`.

In order to make the code independent of absolute paths, you just pass the name of the shared library to `System.loadLibrary()`. The System property `java.library.path` is then used to determine in which directories the VM should look to locate the file.

Together with Eclipse's feature to define user libraries, you can easily add Java libraries that depend on native code to your projects.

Comment: So, there is no association between specific `JAR` and between it's native path? All native paths will be added to single `java.library.path` and will be used equivalently?

Comment: P.S. Also looks like `JNA` ignores this path and uses other variables?

Comment: While OSGi defines a way to include the DLL in the JAR, plain Java doesn't. One reason is that JNI can be used to access standard OS libraries which are installed in a fixed place. As for JNA, see the [documentation how it loads shared libraries](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md)

Comment: Just to specify the question. If you add an external jar to the Java Build Path, does the native library location always need to be set or only if the jar file is outside of the project? Or is it completely uncoupled?

Comment: JAR, build path and native libraries are three things. Don't confuse them. A JAR is on the build path, so the compiler can check types. The Java compiler doesn't check DLLs (native libraries). So native libraries are irrelevant when you *compile* your code. At runtime, you need to add the JAR to the *classpath* and the DLL to the `java.library.path`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the [Java Build Path](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm?cp=1_4_9_0_0_0) configuration?

You may need this location if your project uses [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) or [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access). This directory is the location of native code (e.g. a Windows DLL written in C.)

I don't think this information is actually required until you try to run the code. You could provide this information via the [Run Configuration](/questions/661320/) for example.