# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gurobijni90 in java.library.path

Tags: java, gurobi, unsatisfiedlinkerror, java.library.path

I own an academic license for Gurobi.
I followed the guide, but ended up with a problem.
The steps I went through are:

1. downloaded the Gurobi .tar.gz
2. extracted it in the /opt folder with the command `tar xvzf gurobi_installer.tar.gz`
3. a folder named "gurobi902" was created in the /opt folder after the extraction
4. run the command `grbgetkey xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx` to activate the license
5. wrote the following lines in the .bashrc and .profile files

```
export GUROBI_HOME="/opt/gurobi902/linux64"
export PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/lib"
```

6. opened Eclipse and edited the build path of my project and added the external jar of gurobi.jar

When I run the java program in Eclipse I get the message

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gurobijni90 in java.library.path
```

My system has:

- Operating System: Manjaro Linux
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.70.0
- Qt Version: 5.15.0
- Kernel Version: 4.19.126-1-MANJARO
- OS Type: 64-bit

How can I solve it?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Native library location" entry do in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768008/what-does-native-library-location-entry-do-in-eclipse)

Comment: No, I already edited the variables in the files, but I don't know how to proceed and successfully run the code

Comment: You don't edit variables in files in Eclipse, you set project settings as per the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write what worked for me.

1. Remove from `/opt` all the Gurobi installation folders
2. Reinstall Gurobi with a new license
3. Set the Path variables correctly, as written in the Gurobi wiki
4. Relaunch IntelliJ with the default settings (from File -> Launch with default)
5. (optional) specify again the Path variables in the launch configuration
6. Run the program

If it still doesn’t work, run:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/gurobi951/linux64/lib/libgurobi95.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /opt/gurobi951/linux64/lib/libGurobiJni95.so /usr/lib
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you simplify the problem by testing whether the problem involves the Eclipse configuration, or something more basic. Specifically, your Gurobi installation has an examples/build subdirectory where you can build one of the Java examples provided.

Go to that directory and do `make -f Makefile Mip1` and see if that example compiles and runs successfully. If so, then you can focus on the Eclipse setup. If not, you have a simpler example with which to work.